# Linear section of a smooth variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X \subset \mathbb{P}^{N}$ be a non-degenerate smooth variety with positive dimension. Take $x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}$ general points on $X$, with $\mathrm{codim}(X) \geq n - 1$. Denote by $P$ the $(n - 1)$-plane generated by the points $x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}$. It seems that, if the intersection $P \cap X$ is a curve, then it must be irreducible. Is it true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if $\mathrm{codim}(X) > n - 1$, then by the Trisecant Lemma $P \cap X = \{ x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n} \}$, and therefore, $P \cap X$ is not even a curve.

Assume $\mathrm{codim} = n - 1$. In this case, we can apply the Trisecant Lemma only for $(n - 2)$-planes generated by $n - 1$ of the general points $x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}$. Let $E$ be an irreducible component of $P \cap X$. Let $P'$ be the $(n - 1)$-plane generated by $x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n-1}$. By Bézout Theorem, $E$ intersects $P'$. But, by the Trisecant Lemma, $P' \cap X = \{ x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n-1} \}$. Thus, we can assume that $x_{1} \in E$. Let $P''$ be the $(n - 2)$-plane generated by $x_{2}, \ldots, x_{n}$. By Bézout Theorem, $E$ intersects $P''$. But, by the Trisecant Lemma, $E \cap P'' = \{ x_{2}, \ldots, x_{n} \}$. Thus, we can assuume that $x_{2} \in E$. If $\deg(E) = 1$, that is, $E$ is a line (joining two general points), then $X \cong \mathbb{P}^{N}$, and in this is not the case by the assumption on the codimension of $X$. Assume $X \not\cong \mathbb{P}^{N}$. Then we have $\deg(E) \geq 2$. We repeat the reason (applying Bézout and Trisecant Lemma), and conclude $x_{3} \in E$. Recalling that a non-degenerate irreducible curve $C$ in $\mathbb{P}^{d}$ of degree $d$ is a rational normal curve, we will have the degree of $E$ at least the number of points $x_{i}'s$ in $E$, unless $X$ is a quadric hypersurface (this is a consequence of Kobayashi-Ochiai's Theorem). Therefore, we conclude that $E$ contains all the points $x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}$; in particular, $P \cap X$ is irreducible. Now what is important: $E$ is also a normal rational curve, by the previous result that I just mentioned. And again by the Kobayashi-Ochiai's Theorem, $X$ is isomorphic to a quadric hypersurface. Conclusion: the hypothesis $P \cap X$ curve happens only for projective spaces and quadric hypersurfaces, in which cases the result holds.

Answer (score 0):

The Segre threefold in $\mathbb{P}^5$, given by the image of $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^2$ under $([a:b],[x:y:z]) \mapsto [ax:ay:az:bx:by:bz]$, is a counterexample.

It has codimension $2$, but it meets the $2$-plane $T_0=T_1=T_3=0$ in the union of two lines, $T_0=T_1=T_2=T_3=0$ and $T_0=T_1=T_3=T_4=0$.

At this time, I'm unsure about surfaces in $\mathbb{P}^4$, but there might be an example in similar spirit.

Comment: Dear @Slade it seems that you are not taking the 2-plane generated by 3 general points. For a counter-example, you should prove that there is no non-empty open subset such that for 3 of its points the plane generated by these points intersects the variety in a reducible curve.

Comment: @rla The two lines meet at a point, so they contain three points that generate the plane.  You should really try to clarify in the question what you mean by "general"—it sounds like what you want is to take general points on a single component of the intersection.